# A USB keypad slows Windows wakeup time to minutes

Tags: windows, boot, windows-11

I bought this cheap USB keypad. Nothing fancy. Not programmable, no LED lights etc. Just numbers and Enter.

When it is connected and I put the PC to hibernation for a night, next morning waking up takes 3-4 minutes. **Reboot** however seems to be OK, only wake up from hibernation is affected.

If I disconnect it before hibernation it only takes 35sec to wake up.

The **most time it is spent showing BIOS poster** (the picture with BIOS name and text like "press F2.." etc).

**How do I investigate it?**

*This is custom built PC on Asus MB, Windows 11, the main keyboard and mouse are connected to a PCIe PS/2 card*

I did some basic stuff I could Google:

1. turned on boot log - dont understand what to look for
2. sfc /scannow - OK
3. dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth - OK
4. chkdsk /scan - OK

excerpt from the boot log - devices which werent loaded - dont know if it means anything:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Version 10.0 (Build 22000)
 6  1 2022 11:31:52.500
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CAD.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\wd\WdFilter.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\wimmount.sys
```

Comment: Are the USB devices like that keypad powered when the computer is hibernated? I would recommend to disable in BIOS the "poster mode" so you could see if there are warnings or errors shown while the BIOS is booting up.

Comment: Hmmm... it is *possible*, though unlikely, that the keyboard or even tiny dongle contain malware.: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/heres-a-list-of-29-different-types-of-usb-attacks/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - sure, everything possible in this world but I highly doubt it, plus that king of malware is made in state sponsored labs and unlikely to cause such obvious issues. What malware would be doing for 3 minutes on a computer which is in 95 percentile in power.

Comment: @Robert - it is probably powered I need to check. switch off poster mode - Ill try and report back. thanks

Comment: @Robert - the ports in question are powered even in hibernation. These are the desktop face USB ports. I used them to connect to various devices in the past and never had the issue. I switched off the BIOS poster and there is nothing there - its just blank screen for 3 min.. then windows kicks in with 4 blue squares and a waiting icon for 20 sec then login screen appears.