# Why Windows Performance Analyzer has Tracing Off for Boot Phases

Tags: windows, performance, hibernate, windows-11

I am trying to find out why my desktop sometime takes 3-4 min to wake up from hibernation.

I installed WPA part of ADK - windows performance recorder and analyzer.

I set up recorder as follows - selected Hibernate scenario:
[image]

But the results doesnt have data in the `Boot Phases` list - see the pic

**Can someone explain please - why and what do I have to do to investigate waking up problem?**

[image]

Comment: this is the time where the device is off. First part is hibernate, the data after "tracing off" show the resume. apply the Hibernate.wpaProfile to see more details about what is taking which time

Comment: ok, I see you already know the [cause, it is this USB device](https://superuser.com/q/1724429/174557). I also had boot delays when USB3 hub was attached. attack it to a different device and if you see the same error, you know for sure the USB device is the cause.